# Como alinhar DIV´s na horizontal sem que elas quebrem de linha?

Tags: css

Tenho as seguintes CSS:

```
div.config-pai{
    width: 100%;
}
div.config-pai div{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color:#666;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Veja minhas DIV´s:

```
<div class="config-pai">
        <div>Adicionar</div>
        <div>Adicionar</div>    
        <div>Adicionar</div>    
        <div>Adicionar</div>    
        <div>Adicionar</div>
</div>
```

As DIV´s internas ficam horizontalmente, mas a última passa para a linha debaixo porque estou utilizando `margin`, como resolver isso?

Preciso que todas fiquem em uma única linha horizontal e que se redimensionem de acordo com a largura do navegador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o ***[flex box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)***, mas veja a compatibilidade de navegadores para o seu propósito. Algumas versões pré-modernas de navegadores não dão suporte, como o IE 9 pra baixo (veja no **[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)**).

Adicione `display: flex;` na *div pai*:

```css
div.config-pai{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
div.config-pai div{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color:#666;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

```html
<div class="config-pai">
   <div>Adicionar</div>
   <div>Adicionar</div>    
   <div>Adicionar</div>    
   <div>Adicionar</div>    
   <div>Adicionar</div>
</div>
```